# Javascript: Using string and enum values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, enums

I've got a situation where I need to use both a string and an Enum value and I don't know how to do so.

Here is an example:

```
var iffyChoice = item.createChoice('Peanut', pageBreak);
```

I have no problem using an array for the first value but I have no idea how to put in the second Enum value.  Putting `'Peanut', pageBreak` as a value in the array does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "enum value"?  Javascript doesn't have an enum type.

Comment: As you can see from my code example the first value is in quotes and the second is not.  Every time I push an array it puts the value in quotes like that.  I don't know how to do the second value.  I'm calling it an enum value because that's what Google calls it...   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-navigation-type

Comment: Where are you calling `push`?  I didn't see it in the code you posted or linked to. The second value isn't in quotes because it's a variable.  Additionally `pageBreak` isn't an enum value.  Enum values, as it says in the docs, are prefixed with `FormApp.PageNavigationType`.

Comment: OK, I think I get it now.  I figured I was asking the wrong question and now thanks to you I understand why!